# search value of index in indexed array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, associative-array

Let's take an indexed (associative) array as shown below

```
var gh = { pop: 'apple', jim: 'orange', john: 'ball', sim: 'oran' }
```

How can I search this array to find the indexes where the value is like 'ora'?

Example:

If I given input `ora` I have to get indexes `jim` and `sim` as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're needing the keys of Object whose value matches certain pattern. You could use `[].filter` on `Object.keys(gh)` which returns an Array of keys for the Object passed in.

```
var str = "ora", gh = { pop: 'apple', jim: 'orange', john: 'ball', sim: 'oran' };
var output = Object.keys(gh).filter(function(key){  
    return gh[key].indexOf(str) == 0; // condition
});
```

Use the condition `gh[key].indexOf(str) > -1` if `str` can appear anywhere in the `String` not just at the start. You could see the contents of `output` Array by logging it

```
console.log(output);
```

If you want to get them as Array of `{key:value}` as you've stated in the comments, you could do

```
var result = output.map(function(k){ 
   var obj = {};
   obj[k] = gh[k];
   return obj;
});
```

Comment: can we build a new array with the searched outcomes. It should be like {jim : 'orange', sim: 'oran'}

Comment: The output array contains only keys. How can I get values too